# Downgrading Windows 8 -> Windows 7 without disk/usb drive

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, setup

Our new PC just arrived, with Windows 8.1 pre-installed. But i want to have Windows 7 on it. The only USB-drive i have is a 1-TB external harddisk(which has a Win 7 .iso file(3gb) on it).

What i tried so far:

- Using the "Windows 7 USB/DVD Downloadtool", I tried copying the .iso onto an USB stick. The program stopped at about 30% and spit out an "Unknown Error"
- I tried to program above with a 4gb DVD. But after the 97% it said "Could not copy image to DVD. Please check the file and your DVD and try again." or something like that.
- Resizing the partitions on the target PC so i have 2 partitions. One Win8 and an empty one. The I tried installing Windows 7 directly from Windows 8 using Winrar to extract the setup from the .iso. The setup ran without problems, but during the second step("Expanding files") the setup rebooted the PC. After the reboot, I was shown a bootmanager with the following options:

  Windows Setup
  Windows 8
  When trying to start the 1st one, I only get an error screen telling me, that some driver signature could not be verified. The second options just works fine.

How can I install Windows 7 on my PC?

~Mystery

Comment: "How can I install Windows 7 on my PC?" - You download the .ISO again because the one you have is corrupt.  You cannot install Windows 7 without installing it and that requires a bootable disk.  Your external drive does not meet that requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ramhound is probably at least mostly correct. It sounds like you're using a corrupt Win7 install image. That shouldn't have stopped you from copying it to a flashdrive, unless you were unpacking the image as you do so (which is necessary to boot off the flashdrive, along with making the drive bootable by setting its partition as Active; use `diskpart` for this) but that would explain the other problems.

In general, the process to install Windows these days is to obtain an install image. You should make sure it's correct; the SHA1 hashes of the official images are available [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/#searchTerm=Windows%207&ProductFamilyId=0&Languages=en&ProductFamilyIds=350&FileExtensions=.iso&PageSize=10&PageIndex=0&FileId=0) even without a subscription (click the "Details" button for the version you have to see the SHA1 digest). Then either burn that image to a DVD (as an image, *NOT* as a file) or unpack it to a bootable flashdrive (you make a flashdrive bootable by formatting it with FAT32 and marking the partition as Active; the `diskpart` tool built into Windows can do this). To unpack a .ISO image, you can use a tool like 7-Zip or can just mount the image as a virtual disk (Win8 has support for this operation built in, though Win7 does not). After making the flashdrive bootable, you just copy the files over using Windows Explorer or whatever file management tools you want to use. Boot off either the flashdrive or the DVD and follow the steps.

Be aware that Win7 will probably not fully support your new computer's hardware! It's about six years old now, and lacks support for now-common hardware such as USB3 ports. You can probably download Win7 drivers that will get that hardware working, but I recommend that you do so before installing the OS because it's quite possible that the network interface will be one of the things that doesn't work initially. It is OK to have other files on the flashdrive beyond just the Windows installer, so you can stash your downloaded drivers and such there before rebooting to install.

Comment: You can strip stream USB 3 support into the .WIM easily enough